# responsive div overlay with twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap with wordpress and want to display boxes with a featured image and some text, it looks like that:

```
      <div class="span2 first-page-article">
        <?php while (have_posts()) :the_post(); ?>
            <?php if (has_tag('start-smaka')) : ?>
                <?php 
                    if (has_post_thumbnail()) 
                    {
                ?>
                    <div>
                      <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php
                    } 
                ?>
                <div class="first-page-article-description">
                    <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2> 
                    <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endwhile ?>
      </div><!--/span-->
```

I did my own grid (10cols, 80width with 16 gutter) and uploading featured image 220px*220px and than I have 220px min-height on first-page-article-description; that way I get a box that is 220px width and 440px height (it was important that the text box has the same size as the image). Now I want to make en overlay effect on div hover. I was trying to use that plugin: http://www.backslash.gr/demos/contenthover-jquery-plugin/ (example 4) but its breaking the site; it's no longer responsive. Does anyone know how to sole it?